# Using JW player getting errror loading file media could not be played

Tags: html, iis-7, jwplayer

I am new user of jw player ..Please help guys :(

`i use these files in head of html`

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">jwplayer.key="ABCDEFGHIJKLMOPQ";</script>
```

this is my setup

```
<div id="myElement5a">Loading the player...</div>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                jwplayer("myElement5a").setup({

                    height: 480,
                file: "vdo/9.mp4",
                file: "vdo/9.ogv",
                    abouttext:" MUHAMMAD FARID ALAM, FCA",
                aboutlink:"http://www.mfaridalam.com/",
                    image: "images/p1-fix.jpg",
                    startparam: "starttime",
                    width: 740
                    });
                    </script> 


        </div>
```

When i play this on laptop without using internet server its working fine in all browser localy but when i upload this on my web hosting server which has ms window 2008 server ....
I am getting this error

errror loading file media could not be played

Please help i need to make my web site live in few hours ..

I am new user of jwplayer i dont i just check one script file jwpleyr.js its say jwplayer.version="6.3.3242"
So i guess its jwplayer.version="6.3.3242"

Thank you if you have any solution let me know

Comment: Do you have a link to where this is running?

Comment: http://www.mfaridalam.com/beta/interview.html  we are  running iis 7 on window 2008 server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about the stop() issue?

But you need to make sure both OGV and MP4 MIME TYPEs are set, and that the player is set up like:

```
<script>
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
      playlist: [{
        image: "/uploads/myPoster.jpg",
        sources: [{
          file: "/uploads/myVideo.mp4"
        },{
          file: "/uploads/myVideo.ogv"
        }]
      }]
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thats really working fine now please tell me how to add this in your setup                           <code>abouttext:" MUHAMMAD FARID ALAM, FCA",
   aboutlink:"http://www.mfaridalam.com/",
        image: "images/p1-fix.jpg",
        startparam: "starttime",
        width: 740</code>and how to stop video in IE

Comment: i sort out that setup please help me hot to stop video on IE

Comment: What do you mean by the stop in IE?

Answer (score 1):

Your web server does not have the OGV MIME TYPE set up properly.

This file - http://www.mfaridalam.com/beta/vdo/8.ogv

Has the MIME TYPE - text/plain

But it should have this MIME TYPE - video/ogv

That is your issue, indeed.

Comment: please tell how to add mime type ?

Comment: I use Apache, never used IIS 7. You can ask your host, or maybe add it in a config file, but that it outside of my area of expertise.

Comment: Now its running fine on google crome and fire fox  after i add mime type ..but stil not running on internet explorer but when i remove     file: "vdo/1.ogv", from jwplayer("myElement").setup({ then its run on file: "vdo/1.mp4", then its run but i face other problem video not stoping i use this function jwplayer("myElement").stop();

Comment: Need to add another note below.

Comment: I added it below as a 2nd answer. Did you not even see it?

Comment: If you are still having issues with the stop(), please put up a bare bones example of such.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure header content type should be according to your video file extension. you need to set video/mp4, video/ogv on your server.

Comment: It is not the answer to the question. Please add it in the comment of the question. Once you earn enough reputation. You can able to comment in the question.